# Displaying JSON data from an ajax call onto HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am working on a project and have everything almost figured out. I am attempting to get a an array of items displayed up on a web page from an ajax call. The code that I currently have is the following:

JQuery Code:

```
    var submit_form = function(w) {
     $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/death_numbers', {
        number: $('input[name="number"]').val(),
     }, function(data){
        $.each(data, function() {
            alert(data.wars_found);
             $('#war_result').text(data.wars_found);
        });
    });
    return false;
};

 $('a#calculate_two').bind('click', submit_form);

});
```

Now the line: alert(data.wars_found); will alert me everything that I want. If I do alert(data.wars_found[3]); It will give me the value that I want. So, I know that I have the data correct. The problem is how do I display this data up on the web page. Here is my HTML Code:

```
<form>
  <input name='number' type='text'/>
  <span id="war_result">?</span>
</form>
<a href=# id="calculate_two">calculate server side</a>
```

If I do $('#war_result').text(data.wars_found[2]);

It will display one war. However, I want all wars listed on the page. I have spent a few hours looking at posts about the subject and I thought that using $.each would solve the problem. I even tried the following:

```
     for (i = 0; i < data.wars_found.length; i++){
       $('#war_result').text(data.wars_found[i]);
       console.log(data.wars_found)
     }
```

That could console log what I wanted but again I want it up on the web page. I believe, at this point that something is wrong with my HTML code. Thank you for any help. Finally, I am working on a Python/Flask project-however, all the data I am pulling is good. Just displaying it as an HTML element is hard!

Comment: Maybe if you use `$('#war_result').append(data.wars_found);`

Comment: You're iterating over an array, each time updating and therefore overwriting the text of war_result. Maybe try something like this in your for loop: $('#war_result').text($('#war_result').text() + data.wars_found[i]);

Comment: Why not use jQuery to insert <span id="war_result_x">{your war info}</span> elements into the html via a loop over the array of war results?

Comment: @jas7457 that got it to work! Thank you! I will also try other ways to see what I like the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way with your code:

```js
var concatenatedData = '';
for (i = 0; i < data.wars_found.length; i++){
   concatenatedData += data.wars_found[i];
}
 $('#war_result').text(concatenatedData);
```